# three MySQL queries using variables from 1 column of 1 table need to be parsed into a temp table

Tags: mysql, variables, select, subquery, temp-tables

I know T-SQL, but fairly new to MySQL. I would really like to do something like this, perhaps using subqueries, maybe a temp table, probably in a routine. Results for each select has multiple rows of varying row counts.

```
create procedure procname

select col1 into @var1 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.col2 = 1;
select col1 into @var2 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.col2 = 2;
select col1 into @var3 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.col2 = 3;

create temporary table tmpT (col1,col2,col3) insert (@var1, @var2, @var3);
select * from tmpT;
```

however everything I am trying is throwing an error. I apologize if this has been asked already, but I can't find any thread started by anyone who has asked it. oh, btw, I am using phpmyadmin, mysql version 5.6.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX` with `CASE` statement for this:

```
select max(case when t2.col2 = 1 then col1 end) as col1, 
       max(case when t2.col2 = 2 then col1 end) as col2, 
       max(case when t2.col2 = 3 then col1 end) as col3
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.col2 in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I wasn't getting my results right, just one row effected, but I realized I didn't need the MAX operand. However, now I am getting NULL values for the rows of the columns where there is no value. I would expect this, if I had thought about it. Is there any way to remove the null values in MySQL, or is that best left for PHP? (I would prefer to do this in MySQL, I think.)

Comment: @JoshuaPrentice -- remove the `NULL` columns?  Can you explain further?  Would you prefer a different value, if so use `COALESCE`. If you want to dynamically change the number of columns returned, then I'd suggest using your presentation logic to handle this.

Comment: Everytime I use the enter key the comment is made, so I can't really show you what I mean, so let me try to describe it. Let's say there are six total rows. The code above, with an order by 1, 2, 3 desc clause, would look something like this: row1 = NULL, NULL, VALUE, ROW2 = NULL,NULL, VALUE, ROW 3 = NULL, VALUE, NULL, ROW 4 = NULL, VALUE, NULL, ROW 5 = VALUE, NULL, NULL, ROW 6  = VALUE, NULL, NULL. Make sense? SO, I don't want the NULL values returned in the output...

Comment: so if I were doing this in ASP, the code may look something like this in a loop: if null(rs.fields("rs") then response.write '' end if

Comment: @JoshuaPrentice -- You can replace the null values with '' or any value you'd like using `COALESCE()` or potentially `ELSE` in the `CASE` statement.  You can also change your `ORDER BY` to suffice for your desired results.  The posted answer appears to resolve your question though.  Feel free to edit your question or post a new one if you still need additional assistance.